# Underscore and asterisk color in lstlisting string

Tags: lstlisting

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}
\lstdefinestyle{R} {
      language=R,
      showstringspaces=false,
      columns=flexible,
      stringstyle=\color{Orange},
}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=R]
print("This is a test string with_underscore_in_it and one * asterisk.")
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Which results with underscore and asterisk to be in black color instead orange like the rest of the string. Is there any way how to make it also orange ?

[image]

Comment: If you change the `language` to **Python**, this would not happen. So please check if underscore and asterisk mean something special in strings of **R**.